# Splitting an Eclipse/GWT Plugin app into separate projects

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I developed an application in a single Eclipse project using the Eclipse-GWT plugin. Now I would like to move some of my general widgets into a separate Eclipse project. I created a new Java project and wanted to "Add a new GWT module" to it, but the wizard says that "The source folder is not part of a GWT Project." How can I split up my GWT project to avoid building one monolithic thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven and make sure to turn on resource filtering on the project the other depends on:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

For more details have a look at this [blog post](http://www.bitsbythepound.com/gwt-module-using-maven-128.html), and gwt-maven-plugin on [multi-module setup](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup).

Comment: Might be also possible with Eclipse. Have you tried configuring dependencies (depend on the project) and exporting source? Don't remember the exact terms in Eclipse..

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully divided my GWT project into 2 projects. There are some things you have to watch for:

1. You must add the servlet mapping of the first Module into the second Module. This is for the second Module to be able to communicate with the first Servlet.
2. In the build path, add a reference to the first module
3. In the second Module, call the service of the first module and you can use its declared methods as follows:
   Module1ServiceAsync module1Service = GWT.create(Module1Service.class)

Comment: And what were the two project types in Eclipse? Both were Google Web Tooklit projects? Did the Google plugin compile both project into one .war file or did you deploy them separately?

Comment: Yes, both were GWT projects. I haven't compiled them yet using the GWT compiler, I will do it on monday and get back to you on that.

Comment: You have to deploy them seperately