# how do you configure GWT_B to add GWT_A as a dependency? (GWT_A & GWT_B are both GWT projects in eclipse)

Tags: gwt, maven

I have a tough question.
I have 2 GWT projects GWT_A and GWT_B, each in a different root folder. All the porjects are compiled using Maven. GWT_B has its own servlet and uses the one of GWT_A. 

Now my question is, how do you configure GWT_B to add GWT_A as a dependency?

 **PS:** Adding a normal dependency fails because the GWT_B is not finding the packages in GWT_A. 

Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503224/splitting-an-eclipse-gwt-plugin-app-into-separate-projects/8513305#8513305). The trick is in turning on the **resource filtering** so that when you mvn install GWT_A, maven will package the source code which then gwt can pick up when compiling GWT_B.

There's more resources on the web describing how to setup a multi-module project, google for [gwt maven multi module project](https://www.google.com/search?q=gwt%20maven%20multi%20module%20project).

Comment: I cannot test it until Monday. If this is the correct solution, I will mark your answer.
**PS:**
If i provide you with both my pom files, will you tell me what is wrong with them? then i can mark your answer as the correct one.